# How can I create a dependent list using data validation in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, list, validation

I'm creating a drop down list using the code above:

```
            For Each Value In wb1.Range("B6:B" & LastRow)
            Lista = Lista & "," & Value
            Next Value

            Lista2 = Lista & "," & ",A,B,C,D,E,F,G"

            With Cells(30,39).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=Lista2
            End With
```

But now I'm trying to create a dependent list using VBA. I want to put conditions for my list, being dependent on the value of the left column.

If left column value is "AL" or "SD" I want to have Lista & "," & ",A,B" list selection, if "PC" I want to have "C,D,E" and if it's "LV" I want it to have "F,G"

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: You could do this using the [`worksheet_change()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event. When the cell containing your first drop down experiences a change, that event will fire and the code inside of it's subroutine will run. In there you can define your second list based off of `Target.Value` (what was chosen in the first list that fired that event. Best of luck!

Comment: One way would be to use named ranges. something like this: https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/